# Erro: Most Middleware em app nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Executando aplicação nodejs. recebi esse erro: 
executei minha aplicação com o comando **node app.js**

**Versões:**

node: 8.9.2

npm: 5.5.1

express: 4.15.5

[image: erro]

**Código app.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

//load customers route
var customers = require('./routes/customers'); 
var app = express();

var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4300);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

/*------------------------------------------
    connection peer, register as middleware
    type koneksi : single,pool and request 
-------------------------------------------*/

app.use(

    connection(mysql,{

        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : '',
        port : 3306, //port mysql
        database:'nodejs'

    },'pool') //or single

);



app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/customers', customers.list);
app.get('/customers/add', customers.add);
app.post('/customers/add', customers.save);
app.get('/customers/delete/:id', customers.delete_customer);
app.get('/customers/edit/:id', customers.edit);
app.post('/customers/edit/:id',customers.save_edit);


app.use(app.router);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**codigo custumer.ejs**

```
<%- include layouts/header.ejs %>
        <div class="page-data">
         <div class="data-btn">
           <button onClick="addUser();">+ Add</button>
         </div>
         <div class="data-table">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">
                <tr>
                    <th width="50px">No</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th width="120px">Action</th>
                </tr>                               
                <% if(data.length){ 

                 for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>                 
                <tr>
                    <td><%=(i+1)%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].name%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].address%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].phone%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].email%></td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="a-inside edit" href="../customers/edit/<%=data[i].id%>">Edit</a>                       
                        <a class="a-inside delete" href="../customers/delete/<%=data[i].id%>">Delete</a>                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% }

             }else{ %>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">No user</td>
                 </tr>
            <% } %>

            </table>
         </div>
        </div>        
<%- include layouts/footer.ejs %>
```

**codigo do costumer.js**

```
/*
 * GET customers listing.
 */
exports.list = function(req, res){
  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

     connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)     {

        if(err)
           console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

            res.render('customers',{page_title:"Customers - Node.js",data:rows});

         });

    });

};
exports.add = function(req, res){
  res.render('add_customer',{page_title:"Add Customers-Node.js"});
};
exports.edit = function(req, res){

  var id = req.params.id;

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

     connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = ?',[id],function(err,rows)
        {

            if(err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

            res.render('edit_customer',{page_title:"Edit Customers - Node.js",data:rows});

         });

    }); 
};
/*Save the customer*/

    exports.save = function(req,res){

        var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

        req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            var data = {

                name    : input.name,
                address : input.address,
                email   : input.email,
                phone   : input.phone 

            };

            var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO customer set ? ",data, function(err, rows)
            {

              if (err)
                  console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

              res.redirect('/customers');

            });

           // console.log(query.sql); get raw query

        });
    };/*Save edited customer*/
    exports.save_edit = function(req,res){

        var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        var id = req.params.id;

        req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            var data = {

                name    : input.name,
                address : input.address,
                email   : input.email,
                phone   : input.phone 

            };

            connection.query("UPDATE customer set ? WHERE id = ? ",[data,id], function(err, rows)
            {

              if (err)
                  console.log("Error Updating : %s ",err );

              res.redirect('/customers');

            });

        });
    };

    exports.delete_customer = function(req,res){

         var id = req.params.id;

         req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            connection.query("DELETE FROM customer  WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows)
            {

                 if(err)
                     console.log("Error deleting : %s ",err );

                 res.redirect('/customers');

            });

         });
    };
```

Comment: Qual a versão do express?

Comment: A última versão. Baixei ontem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro já diz tudo, o *middleware* não está mais disponível nativo no express e deve ser instalado separadamente. Acredito que esteja indicando devido o uso do logger aqui `app.use(express.logger('dev'))`, o que você pode fazer é usar um logger separado.

Exemplo com [express 4](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/migrating-4.html):

**Instalar**

```
npm install morgan
```

**Uso**

```
var logger = require('morgan');
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

Comment: Fiz a instalação porém o erro continua...

Comment: a mensagem agora: like json is no longer bundled with Express

Comment: agora o erro é outro: Most middleware (like urlencoded) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

Comment: quais os pacote que tenho de instalar ?

Comment: Segue os exemlos do link que passei para Express 4, ali tem a forma certa do `urlencoded`, e caso apareça outros vai substituindo conforme o que estiver lá.